# How to print in alphabetical order from a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Using this BST class, I was able to print out the strings, but I cannot figure out how to print them in alphabetical order. Please help. I need to create a method in this BST class where the elements are printed out in alphabetical order. Thanks.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
    {
        /**
         * Construct the tree.
         */
        private BinaryNode<AnyType> root;
        public BinarySearchTree( )
    {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Insert into the tree; duplicates are ignored.
     * @param x the item to insert.
     */
    public void insert( AnyType x )
    {
        root = insert( x, root );
    }

    /**
     * Remove from the tree. Nothing is done if x is not found.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     */
    public void remove( AnyType x )
    {
        root = remove( x, root );
    }

    /**
     * Find the smallest item in the tree.
     * @return smallest item or null if empty.
     */
    public AnyType findMin( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new UnderflowException("No elements found");
        return findMin( root ).element;
    }

    /**
     * Find the largest item in the tree.
     * @return the largest item of null if empty.
     */
    public AnyType findMax( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new UnderflowException("No elements found");
        return findMax( root ).element;
    }

    /**
     * Find an item in the tree.
     * @param x the item to search for.
     * @return true if not found.
     */
    public boolean contains( AnyType x )
    {
        return contains( x, root );
    }

    /**
     * Make the tree logically empty.
     */
    public void makeEmpty( )
    {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Test if the tree is logically empty.
     * @return true if empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    /**
     * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
     */
    public void printTree( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            System.out.println( "Empty tree" );
        else
            printTree( root );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
     * @param x the item to insert.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return the new root of the subtree.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return new BinaryNode<AnyType>( x, null, null );

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = insert( x, t.left ); // if new item < x --> insert to its left
        else if( compareResult > 0 ) 
            t.right = insert( x, t.right ); //if new item > x ---> insert to its right
        else
            ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return the new root of the subtree.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> remove( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return t;   // Item not found; do nothing

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = remove( x, t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            t.right = remove( x, t.right );
        else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
        {
            t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
            t.right = remove( t.element, t.right );
        }
        else
            t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the smallest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return null;
        else if( t.left == null )
            return t;
        return findMin( t.left );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the largest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMax( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t != null )
            while( t.right != null )
                t = t.right;

        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find an item in a subtree.
     * @param x is item to search for.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     * @return node containing the matched item.
     */
    private boolean contains( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return false;

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            return contains( x, t.left );
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            return contains( x, t.right );
        else
            return true;    // Match
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     */
    private void printTree( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t != null )
        {
            printTree( t.left );
            System.out.println( t.element );
            printTree( t.right );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to compute height of a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
     */
    private int height( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return -1;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) );    
    }

    // Node object that stores an element + left and right nodes of the same type
    //*********************************************NEW CLASS*******************************************
    private static class BinaryNode<AnyType>
    {
            // Constructors
        BinaryNode( AnyType theElement )
        {
            this( theElement, null, null );
        }

        BinaryNode( AnyType theElement, BinaryNode<AnyType> lt, BinaryNode<AnyType> rt )
        {
            element  = theElement;
            left     = lt;
            right    = rt;
        }

        AnyType element;            // The data in the node
        BinaryNode<AnyType> left;   // Left child
        BinaryNode<AnyType> right;  // Right child
    }

}
class UnderflowException extends RuntimeException
{
    /**
     * Construct this exception object.
     * @param message the error message.
     */
    public UnderflowException( String message )
    {
        super( message );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do [**in-order traversal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) on a BST, it gives you the nodes in sorted order.

The idea in java-like pseudo code:

```
public void printSorted(node) {
   if (node == null) return;
   printSorted(node.left);
   System.out.println(node.value); //or any other manipulation of the node
   printSorted(node.right);
}
```

(P.S. a better design than what I suggested would be to make the recursive call a method of `BinaryNode<AnyType>`, and before recursing check if `this.left == null` and `this.right == null`, and recurse on them. This is pretty easy to modify it from the above pseudo code).

Comment: I got a stack overflow error using your method. How ironic lol. Anyways, how is this different from the printTree I already have? The root parameter is a little misleading because root is an instance variable, so could you please fix the parameter so I can understand it better?

Comment: @btrballin Actually it's kinda the same. I didn't see your implementation. I don't understand what is the problem then? I'll be happy to edit and help you, but it is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @btrballin P.S. the implementation probably gives StackOverflow because of the `root` multi-usage, and you recurse to the same node over and over (just a guess though)

Comment: The printTree method I posted essentially does the same thing as your code and that method properly prints out the elements, but not in alphabetical order. I need it to print in alphabetical order though.

Comment: @btrballin Is the BST sorted in alphabetical order? If not, you need to re-sort, there is no going away from that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the alphabetical order and the order with which you visit the tree are unrelated, you should decompose your solution like this :

1. Visit the tree in store the strings in a container
2. Sort that container